# Error when submitting form

Tags: python, python-2.7, django-forms, django-1.4, django-sessions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Updating an entry on form submit instead of saving new entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14603968/updating-an-entry-on-form-submit-instead-of-saving-new-entry)

I am editing the form and submitting it, but it is not getting updated, instead it is storing in another entry.

```
def searchinventory2(request, id = None):
    print "sssssssssss", id

    if id is not None:
        task = Inventory.objects.get(id = id)
    else:
           pass     
    if request.method == 'POST': # If the form has been submitted...
        print "dfdf"
        form = Inventory_List(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=task)
        print "hhhhhhhhhhhhh"
        if form.is_valid():
            print "ksjhjksfh"    
            form.save()
            return task(request, 'Task #%s created successfully.' % (task.id))
    else:
        print "in else"
        form = Inventory_List(instance = task)
    return render_to_response("smartlogis/inventoryedit.html", {'form':form,})
```

I am getting this error:

`local variable 'task' referenced before assignment`

Comment: first: adjust the indentation (you have to add 4 spaces in all the code part.

Comment: second: I don't see the connection between the title and the question

Answer (score 1):

`task` is initialised *only* if `is` is not `None`, so if you call `searchinventory2(request)`, task is not initialized.

You should do something like:

```
if id is not None:
    task = Inventory.objects.get(id = id)
else:
    task = something that can be then used
```